# React - JS move property inside an array as a main property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array of data and I want to move **y** property as one of the main property

```
const [data,setData] = useState[{
  id: 1,
  color: '#756083',
  schedules: [
    {
      start: '2019-01-10',
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-02-10',
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-03-10',
      y: 0,
    },
  ],
},
{
  id: 2,
  color: '#756083',
  schedules: [
    {
      start: '2019-01-10',
      y: 1,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-02-10',
      y: 1,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-03-10',
      y: 1,
    },
  ],
},]
```

output should be {id: 1, y: 0, color...} {id: 2, y: 1, color...}

I tried this, the data inside console is correct but its not updating the state.

```
  setData(data => {
    data.map(d => {
      const newData = d.schedules.map(s => {
        return {
          ...d,
          y: s.y,
        };
      });
      console.log(newData);
      return newData;
    });
  });
```

Comment: What is the logic of selecting `y` from `schedules` array?

Comment: You're not returning anything inside the callback passed to `setData`.

Comment: fwiw, i think you should initialize your state with state at right format, and not format on `setData`

Comment: @HassanImam hard to explain, just needed to put it outside sorry, as mentioned the console.log data works, but not setting the state.

Comment: @RameshReddy, tried returning it but im getting 3[array] 3[array] 3[array] and sometimes returning doesnt change the state

Comment: @DrewCordano You have three `y` inside `schedules` which one should we pick? Or do you want each one of them?

Comment: @HassanImam, doesnt matter as long as its inside its own array because it will be use in a chart, thats a y axis so it would be a straight line, hope it made sense

Comment: @DrewCordano Can you share the output for above array?

Comment: @HassanImam  the answer below is what i'm expecting,thanks for the help

Comment: Post the exact object structure, `{id: 1, y: 0, color...}` is vague.

Comment: @VinaySharma, instruction's already there, need to put y outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data=[{
  id: 1,
  color: '#756083',
  schedules: [
    {
      start: '2019-01-10',
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-02-10',
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-03-10',
      y: 0,
    },
  ],
},
{
  id: 2,
  color: '#756083',
  schedules: [
    {
      start: '2019-01-10',
      y: 1,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-02-10',
      y: 1,
    },
    {
      start: '2019-03-10',
      y: 1,
    },
  ],
},]

const res = data.map(d => ({
   ...d,
   y: d.schedules[0].y,
   schedules: d.schedules.map(s => ({ start: s.start }))
}));
    
 console.log(res)
```

```js
setData(data.map(d => ({
       ...d,
       y: d.schedules[0].y,
       schedules: d.schedules.map(s => ({ start: s.start }))
    })))
```